# Impersonate Windows Users for ADODB connection in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, impersonation, adodb

All,

I have two queries to two different databases that I need to complete in the same workbook using two different windows credentials.  I know I can run as different user from the application, but what I am trying to do is find a way to plug the different credentials into the two different ADODB objects.  The problem, of course, is that these are Windows accounts, not SQL Server accounts.

Is it possible to do this at the ADODB level?  If not, is there a way to instantiate (from within VBA) another Application as a different Windows user?

Thanks.

Comment: This is all I could find: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89099d4f-7f70-4134-a138-f6c414a6dc7d/allow-any-user-to-connect-to-sql-database-using-vba-in-excel?forum=isvvba

Comment: This document is about explaining the difference between SQL Server accounts and Windows accounts using Integrated security. It has absolutely nothing to do with impersonation, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Okay. I think I found what I am looking for: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/vba-impersonating-other-user-t974955.html.  Going to give this a shot and see if it works for me.

Comment: Okay, this didn't work (at least, not for me).  I ended up getting ActiveX Component can't create object error at the Set impo = CreateObject("sfImpersonator.Impostor") line.  Using Windows 7.  Back to the drawing board.